# how to understand indexes in lists

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python (3 weeks)
I'm working with this list `a = ["cars", "house", "boat", "family", 5]`
my confusion starts when I type the following: `a[0] == str` which returns `False` or  `a[0] == "cars"`
however when I write `type(a[0])` I do receive str
Please make me understand

And also on given list above, how can I print only strings and exclude integers or floats?

Comment: `only_strings = [x for x in a if type(x) == 'str']`

Comment: @jordanm: Na, better use `isinstance(...)`.

Comment: Use `type(a[0]) is str` instead of `a[0] == str`.

Comment: It's just how python3 was created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048107/what-is-the-difference-between-class-str-and-type-str

Comment: If you know `a[0] == "cars"`, you should not expect `a[0] == str` to be true.

Comment: thank you for your help, now I see where I went wrong.  much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`a[0]` is `"cars"`, which is not equal to `str`:

```py
>>> a[0]
'cars'
>>> a[0] == "cars"
True
>>> "cars" == str
False
```

If you want to test whether the **type** of `a[0]` is `str`, you can call the `type` function, or use `isinstance`:

```py
>>> type(a[0]) == str
True
>>> isinstance(a[0], str)
True
```

So you have made a [reference point error](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/08993408.2014.952500): you wanted to test the thing's type, but you actually tested the thing itself.

In human languages you can get away with saying things like, *"I asked the help desk"*, but in programming languages you have to be exact: you asked *the person at* the help desk, you didn't ask the actual desk.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is usually a check with `isinstance(...)` and to form a new list:

```
a = ["cars", "house", "boat", "family", 5]
only_strings = [item for item in a if isinstance(item, str)]

print(only_strings)
```

Comment: this works perfectly... I still don't know things like isinstance I still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates as True

```
type(a[0]) == str
```

This also True

```
a[0] == "cars"
```

Explanation:
a[0] returns the first element of the list, which is "cars".

type(a[0]) returns the type of the first element. The first element is "cars", so type("cars") is str.